How do I extract a part of an audio clip whose start and end times are given into a .wav file?
I have data on which I have performed Voice Activity Detection (VAD) and this returns a file containing columns of data in the following order : Segment Id, Audio file name, Start time, End time.
For a further task (need to generate spectrograms for each .wav file generated here). I need to go through each line of this file and extract the .wav file from the start time till the end time from the corresponding Audio file.
What I have gathered till now is I need to use ffmpeg , but I cannot figure out how to read each audio file name from the segments file and perform the required operation on it.

The structure of my generated segments file is shown above.
TLDR: Want to extract parts of audio files with given start and end times into .wav files reading the audio file name from the above mentioned segments file.

In Matlab, this would look something like this (conceptual snippet, not tested)
info.audioinfo('B10.wav');
fs = info.SampleRate;

for i = 1:length(start_time)
  x = audioread('B10.wav',round(fs*[start_time(i) end_time(i)]))
  % do something with the segment
end

Python has a plethora of wave file readers (see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/26716031, pyaudio is also a good choice) all with different APIs and capabilities. The best choice depends on your specific application, requirements and constraints and probably on what you already are using. No point importing a new module if one of your existing ones can do the job

Yeah I parsed through each line and used ffmpeg to extract and store. Thanks!
